# SSHD: Get content of readonly-file

Tags: java, nio, apache-mina

On my remote server I have a file which is read-only.

```
$ echo "Hello World" > /tmp/dummyfile && chmod a-w,a-x /tmp/dummyfile && ls -l /tmp/dummyfile
-r--r--r-- 1 dummyuser users 12 Mär 12 12:12 /tmp/dummyfile
```

I want to access my remote server via Java NIO API using Apache Mina SSHD like this:

```
SftpFileSystemProvider provider = new SftpFileSystemProvider(sshClient);
try (FileSystem fileSystem = provider.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap())) {

    Path path = fileSystem.getPath("/tmp/dummyfile");
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    // ...
}
```

When I try to read a readonly-file (like the one above) I get an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" SFTP error (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED): Permission denied
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.impl.AbstractSftpClient.throwStatusException(AbstractSftpClient.java:210)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkHandleResponse(AbstractSftpClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkHandle(AbstractSftpClient.java:225)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.impl.AbstractSftpClient.open(AbstractSftpClient.java:665)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.SftpFileSystem$Wrapper.open(SftpFileSystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.SftpRemotePathChannel.<init>(SftpRemotePathChannel.java:77)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.SftpFileSystemChannel.<init>(SftpFileSystemChannel.java:35)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.SftpFileSystemChannel.<init>(SftpFileSystemChannel.java:31)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.SftpFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(SftpFileSystemProvider.java:423)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.SftpFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(SftpFileSystemProvider.java:413)
    at org.apache.sshd.client.subsystem.sftp.SftpFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(SftpFileSystemProvider.java:95)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

The exception is thrown because SftpFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel opens to file with read and write permission (see [SftpFileSystemProvider.java:420](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/sshd-1.7.0/sshd-core/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/client/subsystem/sftp/SftpFileSystemProvider.java#L420)), but the user doesn't have the write permission.

How can I read the file content of my readonly-file with Java NIO and Apache Mina SSHD?

Comment: As you have already identified `newFileChannel` why don't you call it directly with option `StandardOpenOption.READ` which is translated to only `SftpClient.OpenMode.Read`? Then modes will not be empty and the default modes will not be applied.

Comment: My workaround so far is `Files.newInputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.READ)` and working with that `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think that's an error in Apache Mina's SFTP implementation. The Java API-docs says the default mode is `READ`, while Mina's implementation uses `READ,WRITE` as the default.

I've just filed an PR at Apache's Github project: https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/pull/372

Thank you for suggesting a good workaround!